# Camera app crashes after video intent, but picture intent works fine?

Tags: android, video, android-intent, camera

I am using the camera intent to capture both still images and videos using the default camera app. The method for taking a picture and the one for taking a video are very similar. The picture one works great, it saves the photo to the temporary file I supply the path to in the intent. However the video does not work.

The video intent opens the camera app as normal, and then I record m video, and all seems fine, but when I finish recording or reach one of the limits the camera app just crashes.

This is my code from my activity for calling the camera app:

```
private void takeVideo()
{
       Intent videoIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

       File tempFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MediaTemp");
       tempFolder.mkdirs(); 
       File video = new File(tempFolder, "vid.tmp");
       Uri uriSavedVideo = Uri.fromFile(video);
       videoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedVideo);
       videoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 60);
       videoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0);
       videoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT, (long)(16*1024*1024));

       this.startActivityForResult(videoIntent, 2);
}

private void takePicture()
{
       Intent pictureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

       File tempFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MediaTemp");
       tempFolder.mkdirs(); 
       File image = new File(tempFolder, "pic.tmp");
       Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
       pictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);

       this.startActivityForResult(pictureIntent, 1);
}
```

I do not think that the problem is in the OnActivityResult method because the app that crashes is the camera app and not my own app, so the problem it encounters must happen before my app gets control back in OnActivityResult. But I cannot understand what is causing this crash.. Can anyone offer some insight into this?

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with the Android camera but you might want to have a look at how CommonsWare solved these problems in his library: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera

From the github page:

> CWAC-Camera is an effort to standardize that "ton of code" and hide it behind a scalable API. Here, "scalable" means "simple things are simple, but complex things may be a bit complex".

Credits to https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware